# JQuery - Check if each dynamically added button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have buttons being added to an element via JQuery Ajax and a PHP script.  The number of buttons being added is variable.  I want to be able to check if each button has been clicked before enabling another action.

The relevant code in the PHP script is as follows with each button having an incremented ID:

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<div class='dr_feedback_btn' id='dr_" . $i++ . "'>Feedback</div>";
}
```

I have the following code in JQuery for the button click based on the button class:

```
    $('#dr_container').on('click', '.dr_feedback_btn', function() {
         ...
    });
```

The image below shows the feedback buttons.

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: i understood you question you need to check if button is clicked or not. if clicked than enable event.. But  the sentence `  I want to be able to check if each button has been clicked before enabling another action.` is creating a confusion can you update image to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `"clicked"` class to each button when clicked, and then test if there are any buttons that don't have that class:

```
$('#dr_container').on('click', '.dr_feedback_btn', function() {
   $(this).addClass('clicked');
   if ($('.dr_feedback_btn').not('.clicked').length === 0) {
     // all are clicked, so enable your other action here
   }

   // other click processing here
});
```

The `"clicked"` class can of course be named whatever you want, and need not exist in your CSS, though you might consider giving the user some visual indication of which buttons have been clicked already (and you *could* use the new class for that).

Comment: nnnnnn, brilliant and simple!  Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You need a way to store the information of whether or not a button has been clicked before and then on that final click, know to trigger the display of some other thing. You can store that data in many different ways. One is to use jquery's data attribute:

```
$('#dr_container').on('click', '.dr_feedback_btn', function() {
    $(this).data('clicked', true)
    var buttons = $('.dr_feedback_btn')
    var clickedButtons= buttons.filter(isClicked)
    if (clickedButtons.length === buttons.length) {
        // do your magic here
    }
});

function isClicked(idx, el) {
    return $(el).data('clicked') === true
}
```

You can also rely more on selectors and use html's actual data attributes:

```
$('#dr_container').on('click', '.dr_feedback_btn', function() {
    $(this).attr('data-clicked', 'true')
    var buttons = $('.dr_feedback_btn')
    var clickedButtons= $('dr_feedback_btn[data-clicked=true]')
    if (clickedButtons.length === buttons.length) {
        // do your magic here
    }
});
```